# Extract keywords from text misses some entities

Tags: named-entity-recognition

I have tried a few of the keyword extraction techniques and they work fine. But when I uploaded documents from scientific domains such as medical, genetics, healthcare, many medical or rather technical terms were missed.

What would I have to do to have the algorithm include those as well, am I missing a dictionary of such terms etc?